# How practical it is for a person to give up material needs and become spiritual?

Tags: vedas, bhagavad-gita, sanyasi

What do the Vedas and Bhagavad Gita say about how, one, who wants to devote himself completely to God and give away material success and happiness, should earn a living just enough to have food two times a day and fulfill other basic needs?

In other words, how practical it is for a person to give up material needs and become spiritual?

Comment: First of all is this story related to you, if yes then you can walk the path of karma yoga like Akroor did he lead a life like a normal person but was totally immersed into god while doing his daily activities like his karma or work, so you can do programming, if you are really into god you cannot like or dislike things it is just that you don't get attached to it, this is what has happened in this case. Plus this question is not at all about hinduism so off topic (personal advice continue programming I am doing same, god will create ways to get you that time!).

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  Personal advice questions are not allowed on this site, so I'm closing your question.  If you want to edit your question to remove all the personal details make it more general, so that it's more of a question about Hinduism than a question soliciting personal advice, that may be more acceptable.

Comment: You can try rephrasing your question similar to this: [What is Dharma according to the Bhagavad Gita?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/289/2995). Also look at [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/353/2995).

Comment: @user5155835, all that you are asking can be condensed to 2-line generic question: _What does Hinduism say about quitting one's day job / duties / [swadharma](http://sivanandaonline.org/public_html/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=1155) and seeking the spiritual path full-time?_ On the other hand, 'What should he do?' makes it a personal advice question as Keshav Srinivasan pointed out.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I've edited the question description, added precise question in the beginning

Comment: @sv. I've edited the question description, added precise question in the beginning

Comment: @user5155835 But you should remove all those personal details and just make it into a general question.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan removed details from description

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan please can the question be reopened

Comment: @user5155835 OK, I reopened it.

Comment: @user5155835 One should not give up because he/she has Problems. Person who gives up materialistic in such situation cannot leave those desires permanently. After some time, he will feel or urge for those desires again(in most of the cases). Well. there are some persons who give up and become sanyasins. You can see these questions. http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/599/3500 and http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8929/3500

Comment: @user5155835, I made an edit suggestion, see if it makes sense.

Comment: @user5155835: The question is generic in nature, where answer can be provided quoting any source.  However, the question details are narrowing down the scope to veda or Bhagavad Gita. Please clarify