# What should we believe in- Karma or Fortune?

Tags: karma, astrology

Hindu Dharma(religion) belief on *Karma*(work) and *Karmaphala*(result of work). By which we can say that if we do good work then the result will also be good. And if we do bad work then the result will be bad. But in astrology, It is said that we (human beings) depend on fortune. It does not depend on *karma*. So if we do good work, the fortune will be not changed. Therefore, by astrolog, our behaviour of work in very useless. But Hindu Dharma strongly recommend on good karm. So my question is which should belief in and make inspiration to ahead in life?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [According to Hinduism who is right about free will (Vivekananda or Chanakya)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19358/according-to-hinduism-who-is-right-about-free-will-vivekananda-or-chanakya)

Comment: We should **know**, it's all fortune (i.e. destiny); Yet we should act as of we **believe** in Karma. *"“We must believe in free will, we have no choice.”~ Isaac Bashevis Singer"*

Comment: `Fortune` can be stated as "what might going to happen", but what will happen is depends on `karma`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word 'fortune' is a misunderstood mistranslated misrepresentation of 'adrushta'

Adrushta means 'not-seen'. It can be good luck or bad luck, depending on your karma. If you hit a man, you're arrested by police. This is drishta (seen) karma and karma-phala. If you meet with an accident or win lottery, this is adrishta (not-seen) karma-phala, because the karma you did might be in previous birth or several births before.

If you throw a ball, it will fall down. If you throw it really high, you might forget about it, and sometime later, it will fall down on your head.

'There is no free lunch' is a very apt saying. You are responsible for your karma-phala. It does not mean you ALONE are responsible. Your body, the prakriti, Bhagavan - all are necessary to produce both karma and karma-phala, but except you, all others are neutral parties.