# What is Yoga according to Bhagavad Gita?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, yoga

What is the meaning of Yoga according to Gita? Is there different types of Yoga? Significance of the word "Yoga" used many times in Bhagavat Gita?

Comment: Well basically entire Gita is about Yoga so in a nut shell you are seeking crux of what is mentioned there in Gita.

Comment: Related: [What is the core message of the Bhagavad-gītā? What are some verses from Bhagavad-gītā that one can refer to, to enrich life in general?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16185/1049), @Just_Do_It correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### tl;dr

```
Yoga (the ultimate Union) = SannyAsa (retirement from birth/death cycle)
```

In layman's term, Yoga means exiting the game of life. If you (*Purusha / Kshetragna*) are watching a movie (*Prakruti*) & are supremely bored or disinterested (*UdAsina*) in whatever is happening to various characters (*triguna* interaction) in the silver screen (*Kshetra*)  then despite having eyes & ears opened & munching popcorn (*Indriya bhoga*), you will be completely blank in mind (*Yoga / ni-Sankalpa*) & won't be thinking even a single bit of the movie (*Jeevanmukta*). Provided an exit from the theatre, you won't return to see it again (*Moksha*).

---

### Yoga

Very good Qn. The traditional meaning of Yoga, which is more about keeping mental & physical healths fit, is not found anywhere in Gita. What we practice as Yoga in today's time are merely gymnastics & de-stressing exercises, which is found in various forms & names in all major cultures of world.

According to Gita:

- Yoga = Union with the Supreme One
- Supreme One = true Self or *Atma* (the 'Me')
- Atma = whatever remains after applying "*Neti Neti*"
- *Neti Neti* = applying "not this, not this" on everything
- Everything = whichever is even thinkable
- Thinkable = induces thoughts

So if we join the above chain, then **Yoga tends to renouncing thoughts (any *Sankalpa*)**.

> BG 6.1 - Blessed lord said, without depending on the result of action, the one who performs action as duty -- that is retired (*sannyAsi*) and seeker of the Union (Yogi); and not the one, who's without fire and without action
> BG 6.2 - O PAndava, what they say as **Retirement (*sannyAsa*), know that to be the Union (Yoga)**; Without retiring from thoughts (*Sankalpa*), no one can be a seeker of the Union (Yogi)

<sub>*SannyAsa* - Retirement and *TyAga* - Renunciation are often used interchangeably, due to their proximity of meanings</sub>

Hence,

```
Yoga = SannyAsa
Karma Yoga = Karma SannyAsa
Renouncing result of actions = Renouncing [majority] actions
```

That's explained in detail here: [How do the scriptures describe an ideal Sanyasi?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11178/1049)

Note that result of Yoga is also considered same as the result of *SAmkhya*.

> BG 5.5 — What state is achieved by SAmkhya-s, that is attained by Yogi-s also; Who sees SAmkhya & Yoga as one(same), sees [correctly]

### Types of Yoga

In my observations, based on competitive verses of Gita, 4 types of Yoga are there in descending order:

1. Karma yoga (*sAtvika tyAga*)
2. DhyAna yoga (meditation)
3. GyAna yoga (similar to *SAmkhya*)
4. Kriya yoga (practicing breathing etc.; probably includes traditional yoga)

> BG 12.12 - "Knowledge" (*GyAna*) is surely superior to "Practice" (*Kriya*); "Meditation" (*DhyAna*)  surpasses "Knowledge". "Renouncing result of action" (*TyAga*) [excels] to "Meditation". From renunciation, Peace follows immediately.

Having *Daivi sampada*, which is the inducer of various Yoga & SAmkhya, is traditional *Bhakti*.