# What is the reason , most sages now-a-days not marry?

Tags: marriage, sanyasi, children

Why do most sages in present world not get married and beget children ? Do they do it to not involve them in Moh (attachments) ?

Which scripture tell not to get married ?

Is it best not to get married ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it acceptable for Sages to marry and have a family?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/599/is-it-acceptable-for-sages-to-marry-and-have-a-family)

Comment: Sannyasis do not marry (or leave family after marriage) .. they are not sages but Sannyasis who had vowed to lead a celibate life.

Comment: As far I know there are a pretty well number of sages with children that outnumber the number of sages that didn't have children. Gautama Buddha had a child, Sage Yajnavalkya had 3 children, Rama had two sons, Ramakrishna had a daughter and a son, Sri M had one son and one daughter, Sri Yukteshwar Giri had a son and daughter. In fact, most of the Brahmin gotras in India should be traced back to sages only. A sannyasi who has vowed to remain celibate shouldn't marry,

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha Yes, in past almost all sages were married.This is why I wrote "now-a-days". Your answers have some factual inaccuracy. Gautam Buddha is not Hindu. So, he is not of concern for us. Ramkrishna Paramhans was 100 percent celibate. He never had a child.

Comment: @river Ah, my bad. Ramakrishna was one of 4 brothers. As far as Buddha is concerned, he was in the incarnation of Rama and wedded sita, as he mentioned in Jataka 461, that is considered by a lot of Hindu literature too.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha What do you mean by 4 brothers ? Are you talking about RamKrishna Paramhans or someone else. RamKrishna Paramhans was married but followed 100 percent celibacy from day 1. He called his wife his mother. 
Which Buddha you are talking about ? Buddha or Buddhism or Bhagwan Buddha. Both are different persons.
Buddha of Buddhism was born in Kshatriya family in Nepal but he discarded Hinduism. It is being said that he was incarnation of Vishnu as was born to take bad people away from Vedas. 
Bhagwan Buddha was born in Magadh in a brahmin family.

Comment: @river Ramakrishna didn't have any children. I'm talking about the Buddha of Nepal only, the founder of Buddhism. He himself mentions being Rama in his previous lives in Jataka 461. Now I don't care if you consider him Hindu or not, that's what I'll not waste my time now.

Comment: If you are using the word 'sage' to mean Ṛṣis, then there are no Ṛṣis in current-day, the ones who *are there*, are actually those, who are surviving from previous yugas. If you are using 'sage' to mean saṁnyāsin, then it's important to note that a saṁnyāsin has already taken saṁnyāsa, he can't have vivāha anymore. He can also not have maithuna with anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the reason can be understood by reflecting upon this verse of Bhagwad Gita

Gita 9:25

> Those who worship the demigods will take birth among the demigods; those who worship ghosts and spirits will take birth among such beings; **those who worship ancestors go to the ancestors**; and those who worship Me will live with Me.

The reason why people marry is to have a son out of respect to ancestors.

But in Gita, It is written that those who worship ancestors goes to ancestors after their death
So, some people do not marry in order to think and worship only Krishna or God. Because they want to go to God after death.

It is not like those who have son, can't go to Krishna or God after death. They too can but they too like the unmarried ones have to worship only Krishna or God.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do most sages in present world not get married and beget children ? Do they do it to not involve them in Moh (attachments) ?

Although this is a bit of a short answer, it should be sufficient. Sages don't marry nowadays because... there are no sages.

They are Sannyaasis/Yatis/Brahmachaaris. NOT Rshis. There hasn't been a single Rshis (that's widely accepted to be one) in a thousand or two years. Do not confuse a monk/ascetic/yati with a Rshi. That's all there is to it.

---

It is the Dharma of every (male) person in the Grihasta Aashrama to be married and have at-least one male heir, otherwise the Pitrs fall down to Mrityu Loka (earth). This applies to everyone. Similarly, this also applies to Rshis who are the embodiment of Dharma, of course they will be married and have a son.

> Which scripture tell not to get married ?

No major scripture tells you not to marry, in fact they all tell you TO marry (and have a son).  There's a few exceptions which demote the role of marriage, but those are fringe and ONLY meant for people close to Moksha. For example, one Yoga Upanishat says that Dhyaana is the ONLY Dharma.

I remember reading this in Taittiriya recently, so I'll put this down here.

> सत्यं वद । धर्मं चर । स्वाध्यायान्मा प्रमदः । आचार्याय प्रियं धनमाहृत्य **प्रजातन्तुं मा व्यवच्छेत्सीः** । - Taittiriya Upanishat 1.11.1

Meaning: Speak the truth, walk on the path of Dharma, do not neglect the self-study of the Veda, give the desired wealth (Guru Dakshina) to the Aacharya, **do not destroy the line of descendants** (i.e have male children).

> Is it best not to get married ?

Depends on your goals.

Comment: Is adoption a choice for those who wish to abstain from some bodily conduct?

Comment: so you don't consider adi shankara, ramauja and madhvacharyas to be rishis ? they are even greater, they are avatara purusha jagadgurus coming directly on order of Bhagavan.

Comment: @ram First of all, it's not certain if Ramanujacharya was a Sannyaasi (before beginning Grihasta). Secondly, it doesn't apply to the other two, since they took Sannyaasa before beginning Grihasta. Thirdly, yes, they're definitely not Rshis (last I checked, none of them have seen any Veda Mantra... that's what Rshi means, remember?) and certainly not greater than them. Being a great scholar doesn't make you a Rshi. It's not about a hierarchy, those are simply different things.

Comment: @Haridasa No, the child specifically has to be of your semen. The woman is more or less irrelevant, but the father has to be you. The Vamsha is only passed on among males, and not by females.

Comment: @DushyantShreyaskar Yeah they are not Rishis. In anycase Rishis' acts also not perfect. Only god is perfect. Only words of gods , instructions given by god (like Bhagwad Gita) is perfect.
I was just asking if any scripture tell it is best not to get married. As 90 % of spiritual persons/gurus etc in present age opt not to get married, including Shankaracharyas and other such people who follow the scripture in an orthodox manner.

Comment: @river You don't need to study for 30 years to learn and have a job in a Subject. Dharma gurus are more like professors, don't think you need to be like them just to get a job.

Grhasta is said to be the highest and the most important Aashrama.

Answer (score -1):

Sages cant be branded as never married. But, Sages were witnesses of many invasions on people where main targets were females after wars. These continued from past to present Era.

For above reason Sages did not marry. A female has to think many times to marry a Sage.

कुलक्षये प्रणश्यन्ति कुलधर्माः सनातनाः।
धर्मे नष्टे कुलं कृत्स्नमधर्मोऽभिभवत्युत।।1.40।।

Above explains that if protectors of Sanatana Dharma (Sages) witness or enter into a group of ruined families (either by invasion or bad rules or wars or slavery) the ETERNAL DUTIES to persist human life on Earth (yielding to Divine) may perish.

If duties perish the KaliYuga may face Pralayam. Four Varnas are protected by intelligence of Sages.

Except proper ritualistic arranged marriages, most marriages happen in AGYAANAVIMOHITA (lust that may vary on different females time to time).
Though marriages are Heaven gifts, the humanity must have retained the gifts with proper conduct. Instead humans lost their gifts of Heavy by concentrating more on three gates of Hell :

1. Kaama
2. Krodha
3. Lobhaa

Having realised above fact Sages isolated themselves from more TYRANTS (who were enslaving females and imprisoning males to govern Kingdom).